# c# wpf открыть файл в папке с помощью Hyperlink

Tags: c#, wpf

применял такой код для показа файла в папке через кнопку

```
string argument = "/select, \"" + filepath + "\"";
Process.Start("explorer.exe", argument);
```

хочу то же самое но через Hyperlink

```
string argument = "/select, \"" + filepath  + "\"";
openFile.NavigateUri = new Uri(argument);
```

ошибка Недопустимый URI: Невозможно определить формат URI

Answer (score 0):

решил через Tag

```
openFile.Tag = argument;
openFile.Click += openFileFromLink;


openFileFromLink(){
    System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink hl = sender as System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink;
    string tag = hl.Tag.ToString();
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", tag);
}
```